# How to browse files on my phone?

Tags: bluetooth, android

I have Ubuntu 15.04, Samsung Galaxy 4.

I can connect the phone and the PC but not browse the files from the PC.

Comment: have you tried enabling USB mass storage in your Android device ? also unlock your phone and then try and open it in your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Plugging it in by USB worked. Why won't it do it via Bluetooth?

Comment: I've never tried to connect my phone to my PC using Bluetooth as USB is much more secure and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same problem. To fix it un

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Once that's installed, plug in the phone to your computer. If nothing happens, on the phone go to Settings > Storage > Upper Right Corner (⋮) > USB Computer Connection > Media Device.

Comment: No, it didn't work. There isn't the option "USB Computer Connection > Media Device." in the Storage options.

Answer (score 0):

run

**sudo apt-get install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9**

then

**sudo apt-get dist-upgrade** 
 run
**sudo nano /etc/fuse.conf**
We want to remove the # from the below line of code for user_allow_other, like so...

Code:

> *#/etc/fuse.conf - Configuration file for Filesystem inUserspace(FUSE)* 
>  *#Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.*
>   *#The default is 1000*
>   _#mount_max = 1000_
>   _# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options._
>   user_allow_other_

*Connect your device via an available usb port and from terminal*
 run  **lsusb**
This should bring up an output similar to the following:

> *Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0fce:01b1 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB*
>   *Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub*
>   *Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub*
>   *Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub*
>   *Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub*
>   *Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0461:4d65 Primax Electronics, Ltd*
>   *Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]*   
> You need to look for your device, in this instance my Sony Tablet is at the top of the list, the vendor id is 0fce and product id is 01b1

now run

**sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/69-mtp.rules**

Then add the below line of code

> > # Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet
> >     ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", ATTR{idProduct}=="01b1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"

now run

**sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**

Then add the following line of code

> ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", ATTR{idProduct}=="01b1", MODE=”0666"

Once that is done and the file is saved, remove any usb device currently connected and issue the following commands

**sudo service udev restart**

**sudo reboot**